# stored procedure inserting values in wrong columns

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures

I am facing a strange problem,
My c# program is inserting values into database(basically checks if the record exists then updates it, otherwise, inserts into the table)

the query for the stored procedure as well as table is shown below:

**Table**

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[PurchaseReceiptbySheetOil](
[id] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
[LPOId] [int] NULL,
[POLineNumber] [nvarchar](100) NULL,
[Serial] [nvarchar](100) NULL,
[DateLoaded] [date] NULL,
[truck] [nvarchar](100) NULL,
[Trailer] [nvarchar](100) NULL,
[Transporter] [nvarchar](100) NULL,
[Driver] [nvarchar](max) NULL,
[PassportNumber] [nvarchar](100) NULL,
[ObserverdVolume] [nvarchar](100) NULL,
[Terminal] [nvarchar](100) NULL,
[Tank] [nvarchar](100) NULL,
[TempInTank] [nvarchar](100) NULL,
[VCF20] [float] NULL,
[VolumeLTS20C] [float] NULL,
[Density20C] [float] NULL,
[WeightMTons] [float] NULL,
[Destination] [nvarchar](max) NULL,
[BottomSEALNRS] [nvarchar](max) NULL,
[TopSealNRS] [nvarchar](100) NULL,
[SAMPLESEALNRS] [nvarchar](max) NULL,
[PhysicalDipsOnTheTruckinMM1] [int] NULL,
[PhysicalDipsOnTheTruckinMM2] [int] NULL,
[PhysicalDipsOnTheTruckinMM3] [int] NULL,
[PhysicalDipsOnTheTruckinMM4] [int] NULL,
[PhysicalDipsOnTheTruckinMM5] [int] NULL,
[PhysicalDipsOnTheTruckinMM6] [int] NULL,
[Site] [nvarchar](100) NULL,
[LineNumber] [int] NULL,
[CreatedOn] [datetime] NULL,
[UpdatedOn] [datetime] NULL,
[CreatedBy] [nvarchar](100) NULL,
[UpdatedBy] [nvarchar](100) NULL
)
```

**Stored Procedure**

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[CreateUpdatePurchaseReceiptbySheetOil]
@Site nvarchar(100),
@CreatedOn datetime,
@UpdatedOn datetime,
@CreatedBy nvarchar(100),
@UpdatedBy nVarchar(100),
@DateLoaded date,
@truck nvarchar(100),
@Trailer nvarchar(100),
@Transporter nvarchar(100),
@Driver nvarchar(max),
@PassportNumber nvarchar(100),
@ObserverdVolume nvarchar(100),
@Terminal nvarchar(100),
@Tank nvarchar(100),
@TempInTank nvarchar(100),
@VCF20 float,
@VolumeLTS20C float,
@Density20C float,
@WeightMTons float,
@Destination nvarchar(max),
@BottomSEALNRS nvarchar(max),
@SAMPLESEALNRS nvarchar(max),
@PhysicalDipsOnTheTruckinMM1 int,
@PhysicalDipsOnTheTruckinMM2 int,
@PhysicalDipsOnTheTruckinMM3 int,
@PhysicalDipsOnTheTruckinMM4 int,
@PhysicalDipsOnTheTruckinMM5 int,
@PhysicalDipsOnTheTruckinMM6 int,
@Serial Nvarchar(100),
@LineNumber int,
@POLineNumber int,
@TopSealNRS nvarchar(100),
@LPOId nvarchar(100)
AS
BEGIN
if exists(select * from [PurchaseReceiptbySheetOil] where Site= @Site and 
Serial=@Serial and LineNumber = @LineNumber)
BEGIN
UPDATE [dbo].[PurchaseReceiptbySheetOil]
   SET [DateLoaded] = @DateLoaded,
   UpdatedOn =@UpdatedOn,      
   UpdatedBy=@UpdatedBy,
   [truck] = @truck
  ,[Trailer] = @Trailer
  ,[Transporter] = @Transporter
  ,[Driver] = @Driver
  ,[PassportNumber] = @PassportNumber
  ,[ObserverdVolume] = @ObserverdVolume
  ,[Terminal] = @Terminal
  ,[Tank] = @Tank
  ,[TempInTank] = @TempInTank
  ,[VCF20] = @VCF20
  ,[VolumeLTS20C] = @VolumeLTS20C
  ,[Density20C] = @Density20C
  ,[WeightMTons] = @WeightMTons
  ,[Destination] = @Destination
  ,[BottomSEALNRS] = @BottomSEALNRS
  ,[SAMPLESEALNRS] = @SAMPLESEALNRS
  ,[PhysicalDipsOnTheTruckinMM1] = @PhysicalDipsOnTheTruckinMM1
  ,[PhysicalDipsOnTheTruckinMM2] = @PhysicalDipsOnTheTruckinMM2
  ,[PhysicalDipsOnTheTruckinMM3] = @PhysicalDipsOnTheTruckinMM3
  ,[PhysicalDipsOnTheTruckinMM4] = @PhysicalDipsOnTheTruckinMM4
  ,[PhysicalDipsOnTheTruckinMM5] = @PhysicalDipsOnTheTruckinMM5
  ,[PhysicalDipsOnTheTruckinMM6] = @PhysicalDipsOnTheTruckinMM6
  ,[Serial] = @Serial
  ,TopSealNRS=@TopSealNRS
  ,LPOId=@LPOId
  WHERE  Site= @Site and Serial=@Serial and LineNumber = @LineNumber

END
else 
BEGIN


INSERT INTO [dbo].[PurchaseReceiptbySheetOil]
       ([LPOId]
       ,[POLineNumber]
       ,[Serial]
       ,[DateLoaded]
       ,[truck]
       ,[Trailer]
       ,[Transporter]
       ,[Driver]
       ,[PassportNumber]
       ,[ObserverdVolume]
       ,[Terminal]
       ,[Tank]
       ,[TempInTank]
       ,[VCF20]
       ,[VolumeLTS20C]
       ,[Density20C]
       ,[WeightMTons]
       ,[Destination]
       ,[BottomSEALNRS]
       ,[TopSealNRS]
       ,[SAMPLESEALNRS]
       ,[PhysicalDipsOnTheTruckinMM1]
       ,[PhysicalDipsOnTheTruckinMM2]
       ,[PhysicalDipsOnTheTruckinMM3]
       ,[PhysicalDipsOnTheTruckinMM4]
       ,[PhysicalDipsOnTheTruckinMM5]
       ,[PhysicalDipsOnTheTruckinMM6]
       ,[Site]
       ,[LineNumber]
       ,[CreatedOn]
       ,[UpdatedOn]
       ,[CreatedBy]
       ,[UpdatedBy])
     VALUES
       






 (@LPOId,@POLineNumber,
@Serial,@DateLoaded,
 @truck,@Trailer,@Transporter,@Driver,
@PassportNumber,@ObserverdVolume,@Terminal,@Tank,@TempInTank,
@VCF20,@VolumeLTS20C,@Density20C,@WeightMTons,@Destination,@BottomSEALNRS,
@TopSealNRS,@SAMPLESEALNRS,
@PhysicalDipsOnTheTruckinMM1,@PhysicalDipsOnTheTruckinMM2,
@PhysicalDipsOnTheTruckinMM3,@PhysicalDipsOnTheTruckinMM4,
@PhysicalDipsOnTheTruckinMM5,@PhysicalDipsOnTheTruckinMM6,@Site,
@LineNumber,@CreatedOn,@UpdatedOn,@CreatedBy,@UpdatedBy)


END
END
```

**Now when i run the following query to execute stored procedure:**

```
exec sp_executesql N'EXECUTE [dbo].[CreateUpdatePurchaseReceiptbySheetOil]   
@Site  ,@CreatedOn  ,
@UpdatedOn  ,@CreatedBy
   ,@UpdatedBy  ,@DateLoaded  ,@truck  
    ,@Trailer  ,@Transporter  ,@Driver
   ,@PassportNumber  ,@ObserverdVolume  
  ,@Terminal  ,@Tank  ,@TempInTank  ,@VCF20
    ,@VolumeLTS20C  ,@Density20C  ,@WeightMTons  
    ,@Destination  ,@BottomSEALNRS,@TopSealNRS 
   ,@SAMPLESEALNRS  ,@PhysicalDipsOnTheTruckinMM1  
   ,@PhysicalDipsOnTheTruckinMM2  ,@PhysicalDipsOnTheTruckinMM3 
    ,@PhysicalDipsOnTheTruckinMM4  ,@PhysicalDipsOnTheTruckinMM5  
   ,@PhysicalDipsOnTheTruckinMM6   ,@Serial  ,@LineNumber
  ,@POLineNumber,@LPOId',N'@CreatedBy nvarchar(7),@CreatedOn datetime,
   @UpdatedBY nvarchar(7),@UpdatedOn datetime,@Site nvarchar(7),
    @DateLoaded nvarchar(9),@truck nvarchar(7),@Trailer nvarchar(7),
   @Transporter nvarchar(5),@Driver nvarchar(8),@PassportNumber nvarchar(8),
   @ObserverdVolume nvarchar(6),@Terminal nvarchar(5),@Tank 
nvarchar(3),@TempInTank nvarchar(4),
@VCF20 nvarchar(6),@VolumeLTS20C nvarchar(6),@Density20C 
nvarchar(6),@WeightMTons nvarchar(6),
@Destination nvarchar(5),@BottomSEALNRS nvarchar(14),@TopSealNRS 
nvarchar(33),@SAMPLESEALNRS nvarchar(7),
@PhysicalDipsOnTheTruckinMM1 nvarchar(4),@PhysicalDipsOnTheTruckinMM2 
nvarchar(4),@PhysicalDipsOnTheTruckinMM3 nvarchar(4),
@PhysicalDipsOnTheTruckinMM4 nvarchar(4),@PhysicalDipsOnTheTruckinMM5 
nvarchar(4),@PhysicalDipsOnTheTruckinMM6 nvarchar(4),
@Serial nvarchar(5),@LineNumber int,@POLineNumber int,@LPOId int',
@CreatedBy=N'Tanveer',
@CreatedOn='2017-05-08 11:50:24.283',
@UpdatedBY=N'Tanveer',
@UpdatedOn='2017-05-08 11:50:24.283',
@Site=N'Site001',
@DateLoaded=N'20-Apr-17',
@truck='',
@Trailer='',
@Transporter=N'00002',
@Driver='',
@PassportNumber=''
@ObserverdVolume=N'40.000',
@Terminal=N'TOTAL',
@Tank=N'223',@TempInTank=N'30.0',@VCF20=N'0.9915',@VolumeLTS20C=N'39.660',
@Density20C=N'0.8219',
@WeightMTons=N'32.597',@Destination=N' DRC ',@BottomSEALNRS=N' 02697558/559 
',@TopSealNRS=N' 02697560 TO 562+02697564 TO 566 ',
 @SAMPLESEALNRS=N'781845 ' 
,@PhysicalDipsOnTheTruckinMM1=N'1472',@PhysicalDipsOnTheTruckinMM2=N'1592',
 @PhysicalDipsOnTheTruckinMM3=N'1706',@PhysicalDipsOnTheTruckinMM4=N'1832',
@PhysicalDipsOnTheTruckinMM5=N'1808',
@PhysicalDipsOnTheTruckinMM6=N'1362',@Serial=N'00001',@LineNumber=8,
@POLineNumber=0,@LPOId=7
```

the values for the columns get swapped during the insert, Note the value for serial is 0001 but it will insert as 1362 instead of 0001 and for some other columns also the values will change(not all).

1. Please note that I have checked the sequence of columns in insert and
   values sections. I am specifying columns but still facing this issue.
2. I have dropped and created the table again.
3. During debugging in sql
   server, the value is correct when debugging starts i.e.0001 but then
   changes, i don\t know why.

Comment: See [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Sir, i dont think it can be reproduced without the table design query or stored procedure or the execution statement. I tried to keep it concise.

Comment: @TanveerKhan stored procedures don't affect how INSERT/UPDATE statements work. Either you update the wrong columns or you mixed up the parameters in the INSERT statements. As for reproducing the issue, it's easy - add the `create table` statement and a call to the stored procedure that shows that the data was stored incorrectly.

Comment: @TanveerKhan a *better* idea though is to just check which columns are affected and verify that they are specified in the same order in the `INSERT` statement

Comment: Furthermore, `Serial` is an IDENTITY column - that means it's assigned a value automatically by the server. Your code *doesn't* specify any value for it anyway (or you'd get a T-SQL error), so why do you expect its value to be 1? Are you looking at the wrong rows perhaps?

Comment: I tried to check the sequence and found it the same, looking for another pair of eyes who can notice what I couldn't.

Comment: Serial is a separate column. I am not trying to change identity.

Comment: SO isn't a debugging service. Plus, there are no ghosts. `Serial` is an IDENTITY column, so it won't start from 1 for new rows. You didn't mention any other example of "mixed-up" values. Are you sure there is any problem *at all*?

Comment: Yes i tried many times. I can add more execute statements if you would like, i tested 12 lines.

Comment: To put it another way - if there is a problem, you can reproduce it with a 3 column table and DML statements. Can you ? With what schema, what values?

Comment: No, *remove* all the lines. Use only 3 columns and actually show the values before and after

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The sequence of parameters in Stored procedure definition should be the same when we are executing it, I was assuming it is not depending on the sequence but the parameter name and i was wrong.